# Why can't I extend localStorage on IE8 (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'd like to add 2 methods to localStorage.  My goal is to end up with something like this:

```
localStorage.setObject(key, object);
localStorage.getObject(key);
```

This solution works in most browsers but not IE8:

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this[key]);
}
```

After doing some research, apparently I could use Lawnchair.js or work around it some other way.  But I'm wondering *why* it doesn't work in IE8.  I can extend String and Array.  Why not Storage?  How can I find out which objects I can extend and which ones I can't extend in IE8?

Comment: My guess is that the object is an exposed ActiveX object, which means it's defined exactly what it's interfaces are, and trying to add a new method to this object, because this isn't an operation defined by the ActiveX object, is not allowed.

Comment: Always keep in mind that host objects don't have to follow the JS specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **IE**. You also can't extend DOM elements. If you sometimes really-really need to call a function, you can do it via `Storage.prototype.getObject.call(localStorage, 'hello')`.

Also extending built-in objects is not considered as good thing.

Comment: BTW I've found, that with IE9 in IE8 mode `Storage` is not defined and `localStorage` doesn't have a prototype. Maybe, this is the same for pure IE8.