# How can I add custom method to storage class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can I do this ?

```
localStorage.myfunction = function () { ... }
```

If not why ?
Are there any alternative methods ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514705/why-cant-i-extend-localstorage-on-ie8-javascript

Comment: What do you mean @Ecko123? Is it the class?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy sorry, wrong reference, corrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very very careful with modifying the behaviour of objects like this. It is typically better to provide a wrapper for localStorage (or use [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) or another library) to provide the features you want.

In the case that you *do* want to add a method or property to localStorage, you can do so by adding it to it's constructor's prototype:

```
typeof(localStorage.prototype); // "undefined"
localStorage.constructor // function Storage() { [native code] }

Storage.prototype.foo = function () { return 'foo'; }
// setting a method on the constructor allows each localStorage instance
// to inherit and use it 
localstorage.foo() // 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do something like this? use:

```
window.myfunction = function(){
    // do stuff here
};
```

to save your function at browser level.